# Need help writing a wrapper for Hiera yaml data

Tags: puppet, hiera

This post seems like it might be helpful but I haven't been able to adapt it to my needs. The meat of it is:

```
$custom_thing = ('custom_thing',{})
create_resources(param, $custom_thing)
```

[full post on serverfault](https://serverfault.com/questions/578968/how-to-define-multiple-etc-hosts-entries-with-puppet-enc/580550#580550)

Here is my Hiera snippet:

```
limits_limits:
  'nofile.conf':
    'user':  0:999999
    'limit_type':  'nofile'
    'both'  : '131072'
  'nprocs.conf':
    'user':  0:999999
    'limit_type'  :  'nprocs'
    'both'  : '131072'
```

Comment: Of course I have more than one param.

Comment: Should that not be `$custom_thing = hiera('custom_thing',{})`? And should the key not be `limits_limits` instead of `custom_thing`?

Answer (score 0):

## init.pp

```
class site_limits {

   include limits

  $mylimits = hiera('limits::limits', undef)   if ($mylimits) {
     create_resources('::limits::limits', $mylimits)   } }
```

## and /var/lib/hiera/common.yaml:

```
limits::limits:
    'nofile.conf':
       'user'   :  0:999999
       'limit_type':  'nofile'
       'both'  : '131072'
    'nprocs.conf':
       'user':  0:999999
       'limit_type'  :  'nproc'
       'both'  : '131072'
```

That's all you need.

The above generates two files: /etc/security/limits.d/nofile.conf and /etc/security/limits.d/nprocs.conf. They contain one line each:

```
0:999999 - nofile 131072
```

and

```
0:999999 - nproc 131072
```

respectively. (the dash means "both hard and soft limits."